# How to reverse order of table columns in html using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a html table with 10 column (i.e 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ) and i want to flip columns hortizontally  (i.e 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 ) using Jquery...

i have below code for this but this code is very long
can anyone provide short code for this..

```
$(function() {
    jQuery.each($("table tr"), function() { 
        $(this).children(":eq(9)").after($(this).children(":eq(0)"));
        $(this).children(":eq(8)").after($(this).children(":eq(0)"));
        $(this).children(":eq(7)").after($(this).children(":eq(0)"));
        $(this).children(":eq(6)").after($(this).children(":eq(0)"));
        $(this).children(":eq(5)").after($(this).children(":eq(0)"));
        $(this).children(":eq(4)").after($(this).children(":eq(0)"));
        $(this).children(":eq(3)").after($(this).children(":eq(0)"));
        $(this).children(":eq(2)").after($(this).children(":eq(0)"));
        $(this).children(":eq(1)").after($(this).children(":eq(0)"));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

To achieve this you could build an array from the `td` elements within each row, `reverse()` it, then append them back again:

```js
$('table tr').each(function() {
  var tds = $(this).children('td').get().reverse();
  $(this).append(tds);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks @Rory for your Quick reply but there is a problem i have another column and i want to fix this Column because this column have statement and i don't want to flip that column. html table with 11 column (i.e 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 Header) and i want to flip columns horizontally (i.e 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 Header) using Jquery... thanks in advance –

Answer (score 2):

Loop through `td`s and in loop use [`.prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) to inserting element in first of parent.

```js
$("table td").each(function() { 
  $(this).parent().prepend(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Update:**

> @NoumanSaeed: html table with 11 column (i.e 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 Header) and i want to flip columns horizontally (i.e 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 Header)

In this case you should exclude last `td` contain `header` in selector using `:lt()`.

```
$("table td:lt(10)").each(function() { 
    $(this).parent().prepend(this);
});
```

```js
$("table td:lt(10)").each(function() { 
  $(this).parent().prepend(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>Header</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @Thanks Mohammad for your Quick reply but there is a problem i have another column and i want to fix this Column because this column have statement and i don't  want to flip that column.
html table with 11 column (i.e 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 Header) and i want to flip columns horizontally (i.e 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 Header) using Jquery... thanks in advance

Comment: @NoumanSaeed Use `$("table td:lt(10)")` as selector. Check http://jsfiddle.net/ecuqzhd8/

Comment: i am very thankful to you but i observe your above code did not reverse the complete table it only reverse first row, but i want to reverse complete table

Comment: i am very thankful to you but i observe your above code did not reverse the complete table it only reverse first row, but i want to reverse complete table

Comment: you are right,  it did not working for me..but below mention code work for me but in this code header column is not fix as you fix in above code could you please do this for me....
Thanks in advance..

code is

 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('table tr').each(function() {
  var tds = $(this).children('td').get().reverse();
  $(this).append(tds);
});
});
 </script>

Comment: please respond ASAP

Comment: @NoumanSaeed You want i fix code of other user! When you use code, you should ask question from who wrote it. So i can answer question about my codes only.

Answer (score 0):

The answers above are correct but you can also do with css.

**NOTE** Solution is not for table with pagination but if the data is short (one page only) you can give it a try!

```js
if($("html").attr("dir") == "rtl") {
  $("table").css({"direction": "ltr"});
}else{
  $("table").css({"direction": "rtl"});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```